# API key no longer working, but don't know what account it is aligned with

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When calling the YouTube API, we've started getting error responses with the following message:

{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "Project 418176253215 has been scheduled for deletion and cannot be used for API calls. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/projects?pendingDeletion=true to undelete the project.",
    "reason" : "accessNotConfigured",
    "extendedHelp" : "https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/projects?pendingDeletion=true"
  } ],
  "message" : "Project 418176253215 has been scheduled for deletion and cannot be used for API calls. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/projects?pendingDeletion=true to undelete the project."
}

However, I cannot use the link provided because I can't find what account was used to create the key for the API (I've inherited the code).

Is there a way to discover what account aligns with a YouTube API key?

Answer (score 0):

There is no documentation in Youtube API which states how to do this because if you own the API key, logging in the [Google Dev Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) under the given project name should easily display all the API keys being used.